# Angle brackets in TypeScript after interface declaration

Tags: javascript, d3.js, typescript, typescript-typings

There is the following code within the [Type Definitions file for d3-scale](https://github.com/tomwanzek/d3-v4-definitelytyped/blob/master/src/d3-scale/index.d.ts) module.

```
export interface ScaleLinear<Range, Output> {
    (value: number | { valueOf(): number }): Output;
    /**
    * Important: While value should come out of range R, this is method is only applicable to
    * values that can be coerced to numeric. Otherwise, returns NaN
    */
    invert(value: number | { valueOf(): number }): number;
    domain(): Array<number>;
    domain(domain: Array<number | { valueOf(): number }>): this;
    range(): Array<Range>;
    range(range: Array<Range>): this;
    /**
    * Important: While value should come out of range R, this is method is only applicable to
    * values that can be coerced to numeric.
    */
    rangeRound(range: Array<number | { valueOf(): number }>): this;
    clamp(): boolean;
    clamp(clamp: boolean): ScaleLinear<Range, Output>;
    interpolate(): InterpolatorFactory<any, any>;
    interpolate(interpolate: InterpolatorFactory<Range, Output>): this;
    interpolate<NewOutput>(interpolate: InterpolatorFactory<Range, NewOutput>): ScaleLinear<Range, NewOutput>;
    ticks(count?: number): Array<number>;
    tickFormat(count?: number, specifier?: string): ((d: number | { valueOf(): number }) => string);
    nice(count?: number): this;
    copy(): ScaleLinear<Range, Output>;
}
```

I'm confused about the angle brackets `<Range, Output>` after the interface name! I watched a PluralSight course on TypeScript and it didn't mention that syntax.

What's more, when I try and use that in my own code, VS Code tells me this:

[image: error in VS Code]

I know that the way I have my `/// ref<>` and `import` statement is correct, cause it ain't complainging about the other stuff (e.g. `d3Scale.ScalePoint<string>`)

What am I doing wrong? Any clarification would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The angle brackets give generic class names. Go back and read the TS docs about that. See https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html.

Comment: The symbol `Output` couldn't be found on your current context, there is nothing to do with angle brackets, try to import the `Output` class on your file. Also, check the version of what you are currently importing, it may not be compatible with that class